# Whats wrong with this code? creating a deleting variable in different scopes

Tags: oop, refactoring, scope

I've recently seen some code similar to that outlined below.

```
public void someMethod() {
  Lecture lect = createLecture();

  ...

  lect.getLectureSeries().delete();
}


public Lecture createLecture() {
  LectureSeries series = new Series();
  Lecture lect = new Lecture(series);

  ...

  return lect;
}
```

The point being that some object (in this case the LectureSeries) which needs to be deleted at the end of the call to someMethod() is actually created in the call to another method. I'm trying to explain why it should be created in the same scope it will eventually be deleted. ie

```
public void someMethod() {
  LectureSeries series = new Series();
  Lecture lect = createLecture(series);

  ...

  series.delete();
}


public Lecture createLecture(LectureSeries series) {
  Lecture lect = new Lecture(series);

  ...

  return lect;
}
```

The original code has caused some complication tidying things up when things fail so hopefully the benefits will be evident, but has anyone got any ideas on how I can explain the more general principle behind this refactoring? or anyone want to explain to me why I'm wrong?

== Edit ==

The case in question was a test method so cleaning up anything which had been created during the execution of the test was important. I think though that the unwanted side effect of a LectureSeries being created as a result of the call to createLecture() is still something to try and avoid in most cases.

Comment: I understand the technique you want to explain, but I think the example is not well suited: people will use code-1 technique to deal with duplicate code, while the code-2 sample does not seem to present any real advantages at first glance. And both have to deal with the Lecture's object internals, which is the real problem I suspect. Why isn't a cleanupLecture() method more suitable? Then someMethod() would not care about the internals of Lecture and the scope of Lecture (?) would be more visible. Also - why is a Lecture meaningful without a LectureSeries?

Comment: I just pulled an example out of thin air rather than put the actual code I'd seen in. This is just meant to be what I think is the simplest case showing the issue at hand, specifically that a LetureSeries is created as a side effect of the call to createLecture(), and the calling method then needs to have knowledge of this to be abel to properly clean up afterwards.

Comment: I figured that the example was a fake one, but the questions remain valid in my opinion. Also, because you say this was a test method, I would have refactored to a cleanup() method instead of simply invoking delete - I believe this improves code readability and maintenance costs. It's not unusual to have setup()/cleanup() invoked with test methods, test frameworks for Java for example do it automatically if you have them defined.

Comment: I'd prefer the second example, because you're limited in the first example to creating a new Lecture with a completely new LectureSeries object. In the second example, you can pass whatever series, or a new one as Lecture lect = createLecture(new LectureSeries());

Comment: totally agree that the code could be better written if it was a real world application and your suggestion to rewrite it to setup()/cleanup() methods is actually how the actual code is written now. Hopefully my example code doesn't disguidse my point too much though, that since the caller to createLecture() needs to know about the LectureSeries created as a result they should really take responsibility for creating it themselves. Should the createLecture() method get reused by anyone else in future they don't then have to get this special knowledge of the side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with creating object in a method that lives beyond the scope of the method.

In garbage collected languages, the tiding up takes care of itself.

In languages where the programmer must manage the cleanup themselves, the programmer must understand the ownership of the object they receive from the method and their duties regarding releasing it.

Comment: It's specifically relating to a test method which needs to be cleaned up after it had completed, the best example I had of this being dangerous was in C++ code but obviously this doesn't wash in a GC'd language. I've added a comment to the original Q relating to it needing to be cleaned up afterwards

Comment: Accepting this answer, it's the point that when the programmer needs to be responsible for clean up as the issue is really one of making it clear what the responsibilities are and making this easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the argument of "Inversion Of Control". The Lecture object needs a LectureSeries object and it is better this object to be injected into it rather than creating it by itself.

Injecting dependencies into objects is always a good practice. Specific to your case you can also say that the creation and deleting statements should be as close as possible. This certainly increases readability. In the first case I see an item being deleted, but I don't see where the item is created. I need to guess that the item is created in the creation method or search the whole code to find where this happens. Error handling (in case the LectureSeries creation fails) is also easier.